# What happens to an Armorer Artificer's extra infusions if they change their Arcane Armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, armor, artificer, artificer-infusions

Armorer artficiers have the Armor Modifications feature, which lets them improve parts of their Arcane Armor, but also importantly...

> In addition, the maximum number of items you can infuse at once increases by 2, but those extra items must be part of your Arcane Armor.

My question is, what happens to those items if I then put on a different suit of armor, thus making my current Arcane Armor stop being such?

Answer (score 7):

#### The effects of those infusions end. They must be reapplied.

Armor Modifications states:

> the maximum number of items you can infuse at once increases by 2, but *those extra items must be part of your Arcane Armor.*

If you remove your arcane armor and then put on a different suit of armor, this happens:

> *The armor continues to be Arcane Armor until you don another suit of armor* or you die.

The moment you put on another suit of armor, *your arcane armor ceases to be arcane armor*. Since you don't have arcane armor, any infusions that require arcane armor cease along with it. And since there is no rule that states that your infusions automatically transfer to a new suit of armor, they must be reapplied to your new one the usual way.